# Disabling close button VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Is there a possible way in VB.NET to disable the close button of the main form as I've seen in many installer! I don't want to hide it, I want to completely disable it!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the blog post in the accepted answer has been taken offline, the following is a solution for C#.NET:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20379/Disabling-Close-Button-on-Forms

Using the C#.NET to VB.NET [converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) on DeveloperFusion, the equivalent VB.NET solution is:

```
Private Const CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON As Integer = &H200
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        Dim myCp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle Or CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON
        Return myCp
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks for the heads up!
Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Set ControlBox property of  the form to false

Comment: I'm sorry but you didn't get my point! I'd specially made it clear that I don't want to hide it, I want to **disable** it! Anyways, thanks for your help